# network `hbase` is declared as external, but could not be found. You need to create a swarm-scoped network before the stack is deployed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I've below docker swarm cluster.

```
    $ sudo docker node ls
    ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
    iq7i01ns7ku7zrtaemiucoawi *   master.com          Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.2
    g6mug58tld4aikobdv3ic9p9y     worker1.com         Ready               Active                                  19.03.2
    uc13xcl9ttauzkqdz03kbrewt     worker2.com         Ready               Active                                  19.03.2
    c8uhfvyhhlmuxp2p3ei3ymrj5     worker3.com         Ready               Active                                  19.03.2
```

I want to deploy the [hadoop platform](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop) into the cluster.

```
    $ sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-v3.yml hadoop
    network "hbase" is declared as external, but could not be found. You need to create a swarm-scoped network before the stack is deployed
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you need to create your Network first:

```
docker network create --driver overlay hbase
```

in your `compose` you specify the network `hbase` as `external` but it seems there is no such network exists